# Asymptotic behaviour of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n}$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm investigating the asymptotic behaviour of this power series: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n}$$
I messed around with it in Desmos and found that $\ln(f(x))-\frac xe-\frac 12\ln(x)$ appears to converge to a constant as $x\to\infty$, implying that $f(x)=O(\sqrt xe^\frac xe)$. Reassuringly, $\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt xe^\frac xe}$ also appears to converge. $$$$
Are these results correct? If they are, is there a rigorous way to prove them? Is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt xe^\frac xe}\right)$ a known value? Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Check this: [Asymptotics of the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3052328/42969).

Comment: And this: [What's the sum of $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}}{k^{k}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115410/42969).